# Checkbox of collection view take a action without clicking

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, swift2

I'm really confused about this problem of checkbox on `collectionView`.

I'm already create a class component for 'checkbox' : `UIbutton`  and after that i used

with 'collectionview' so my problem when i click on some `checkbox` of item

i found another item has checking after :

if i check `checkbox` of item 1 the other item 6 has checking.

```
class CheckBox: UIButton {
// Images
let checkedImage = UIImage(named: "checkbox")! as UIImage
let uncheckedImage = UIImage(named: "uncheckbox")! as UIImage

// Bool property
var isChecked: Bool = false {
    didSet{
        if isChecked == true {
            self.setImage(checkedImage, forState: .Normal)
        } else if isChecked == false {
            self.setImage(uncheckedImage, forState: .Normal)
        }
    }
}

override func awakeFromNib() {
    self.addTarget(self, action: "buttonClicked:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    self.isChecked = false
}

func buttonClicked(sender: UIButton) {
    if sender == self {
        println(self)
        if isChecked == true {
            isChecked = false
        } else if isChecked == false {
            isChecked = true
        }
     }
  }
}

extension TrackersController: UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return dataSource.vehicles.count
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier,forIndexPath:indexPath) as! VehicleCell

     let vehicles: [Vehicle] = dataSource.vehiclesInGroup(indexPath.section)

    let vehicle = vehicles[indexPath.row]

    cell.txt_mat.text = vehicle.name
    cell.txt_imei.text = vehicle.imei
            cell.check_veh.addTarget(self, action: "selectVeh:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    cell.check_veh.tag = vehicle.id_tracker!.toInt()!
    cell.check_veh.enabled = vehicle.subscription!

    return cell
}

func selectVeh(button: CheckBox) {
    if(button.isChecked){
        vehIds.append(button.tag)
    }else if(!button.isChecked){
        var index = find(vehIds, button.tag)
        vehIds.removeAtIndex(index!)
      //  JLToast.makeText(String(button.tag)).show()

    }    
}
```

[Image of item 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kgZqS.png)

[image]

[Image of item 6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4sQD.png)

[image]

Comment: how do you make difference between the different buttons? by tag? by index path? that is not clear in your original post at all.

Comment: hello , by tag on cellForItemAtIndexPath method i put the id vehicle `id_tracker`(int) and i created a target for my button for put the id of my tag button to the list of integer is that clear ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should store the selected indices in an array and later in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method you need to check if `indexPath` is already there in array or not to show/hide the checkbox.

The appearance of the checkbox is due to the reusing of the cell. The cell's content is loaded every time when cell reappears on screen. So you need to update the content accordingly in `cellForRowAtIndex` method.

Answer (score 0):

You need take one bool variable in Vehicle modal class (Ex:isSelected) and set value for that bool variable like below in selectVeh method

```
 func selectVeh(button: UIButton) {
      button.selected = !button.selected
      let vehicle:Vehicle = vehicles[button.tag]
      vehicle.isSelected = button.selected;
      vehicles.replaceObjectAtIndex(button.tag, withObject: vehicle)
  }
in cellForItemAtIndexPath add below code
cell.check_veh.selected =  vehicle.isSelected
```

Comment: Thank you , but i'm already create a list ids and put it the id of row on the tag button so what the different ? and the list has doing another things but right now this "cellForItemAtIndexPath" method i think it can be the solution so i created a one method and i'm doing another checking but unfortunately nothing change :/

Comment: @MrMehdi where you are changing value for isChecked

Comment: i created a class CheckBox: UIButton that's do everything it's like every checkbox component !

Comment: @MrMehdi then you need you need to change code in cellForItemAtIndexPath method cell.check_veh.selected = vehIds.containObject(indexpAth.row)

Comment: thanks but  i'm already do that like that :   func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier,forIndexPath:indexPath) as! VehicleCell
     
            println("IN")
        
        if !contains(vehIds,cell.check_veh.tag) {
            cell.check_veh.isChecked = false
        }
        
           return cell
    }
but still i get the problem :/

Comment: @MrMehdi you need add else condition also and make sure you adding contains condition after setting tag to button